# Android : Find Angle, and draw Bitmap at that angle?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, angle, degrees

I am porting a game I have made, from Windows (Visual Studio c# XNA4) to Android.

In the game, I need to find the location of the users "touch" (Which I have done), and then "point" the player to this touch location (draw the player bitmap at this angle).

In c# and XNA4, I used the following:

```
Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(playerAngle);
PlayerDirection = Vector2.Transform(up, rotationMatrix);
```

If the players position was

```
x = 200;
y = 200;
```

And the touch co-ordinates were

```
x = 300;
y = 300;
```

How would I make the player "point" at where the user touched?

Comment: arctan ( (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java (I assume you are using Java for Android) you would do the following to find the angle:

```
private double getAngle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return Math.atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm getting somewhere, but the angles resulting from the calculations are miles out. For example, If I touch directly above the player, I get a reading of -163.1467? I would expect this to be "0"?

Comment: It is extremely hard to TOUCH exactly above the player, your finger is too big to have this accuracy! +1 for the answer!

Comment: My Mistake, I was incorrectly submitting variables to the function. Works as expected. [link]http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/what-are-atan-and-atan2-used-for-in-games